# RethinkDB local and cloud clusters connection

Tags: rethinkdb

Just thinking about app arhitecture and whant to know is it possible at all to create local cluster for specific tables and connect it with cloud cluster?

And additional question - is it possible to choose where to create shard (on what machine) for particular table (to show cloud cluster that for this table i need shards in local cluster)?

As example, I whant to have table db.localTable be sharded in local cluster to reduce latency and increase performance due to run queries in local cluster and also have ability to run queries in cloud cluster when local cluster is not accessible. All data between clusters should be consistent.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found the solution: to set specific servers for replicas and servers for shards you should use server-tags and perform changes using ReQL and tables setting. For details see - [RethinkDB - Scaling, sharding and replication](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sharding-and-replication) and [RethinkDB - Architecture FAQ](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/architecture/)